# Get ID for selected item in connected web part

Tags: xslt-list-view-web-part

I have an XSLTListView (RoleAssignments list) web part that is connected to another XSLTListview (Authorities list) web part which provides a filtered listing based on the selected role. I need to get the ID value for the selected item but I don't know how to do this since there is not a check box. Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a Web Part connection, isn't the ID of the selected item passed back to the page on the Query String?

Answer (score 0):

No the ID isn't passed unless you construct the query string in another field via a workflow http://www.wonderlaura.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=daba3a3b-c338-41d8-bf52-cd897d000cf3&ID=70&Web=dbb90e85-b54c-49f4-8e97-6d8258116ca0

I have been trying to do this as well and spent a fair bit of time on this. If I find an elegant solution I will update this post.

Thanks,